# Как вызвать функцию из компонента vue после подтверждения goggle recaptcha

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

Всем привет.

Использую goggle-recaptcha, иницализирую его в функции жизненого цикла компонента

```js
mounted(){ 
  window.grecaptcha.ready(this.createRecaptcha.bind(this))
}
```

```js
createRecaptcha(){
                window.grecaptcha.render(
                    this.$refs.recaptcha,
                    {
                        'data-sitekey': 'Site Key',
                        'data-badge': 'bottomright',
                        'data-callback': 'recaptchaLog'
                    }
                )
            }
```

Как передать функцию в data-callback чтобы вызвать метод из этого же компонента с его контекстом

Comment: `const that = this; ..... 'data-callback': that.myMethods` - так работает?

Comment: Надо попробовать